# If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, why is $X+Y$ normal?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I read that if $X,Y$ is jointly normal, then $X+Y \sim N(\mu_X + \mu_Y, \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2\rho_{XY} \sigma_X \sigma_Y)$.

Is it because a condition for jointly normal of two RVs is that any linear combination of those two variables must be normal?

Is this an IFF condition, i.e., if any linear combination of two random variables is normal, then they are jointly normal, and if two variables are jointly normal, then any linear combination of those two variables are normal?

Comment: The condition you are referring to is a definition of multivariate normal.

Comment: One of definitions of normal random variable $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$ is that for every $t \in \mathbb R^n$, real random variable $\langle t,X\rangle = t_1X_1 + ... + t_nX_n$ is normal random variable, so yes, your condition is an IFF condition (either via definition, or by simple reasoning (depending on what definition of multivariate normal you are working with))